# algorithm package: Comment on "for" loop does not work?

Tags: algorithms, loops

It seems that `\COMMENT` in the `algorithm` package is broken. It gives an error when used in a `FOR` or `FORALL` line, so the first comment gives a compilation error:

```
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{My algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
   \FORALL{$p \in P$}   \COMMENT{loop over all puppies}
   \STATE PatPuppy($p$) \COMMENT{sooo nice!}
   \ENDFOR
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The error is:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
leading text:     \FORALL{$p \in P$}
```

Is there a workaround? I really need to display a comment on that line.

Comment: You've found the answer, OK. Next time you should make sure that you post everything that we need to reproduce the problem, including the preamble (like `\documentclass{article}...\usepackage{...}`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is given in the manual. Use an optional argument.

```
\FORALL[loop over all puppies]{$p \in P$}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The comment has to be embedded in the `\FORALL`:

```
\FORALL{$p \in P$ \COMMENT{loop over all puppies} }
```