# Algorithmic package for loop and comment at the same line

Tags: line-breaking, algorithms, pseudocode

I want to have the following output using algorithmic package:

```
for i = 1 : z do // number of rows
   x = 1 
end for
```

I use the following tex code:

```
\begin{algorithmic}
    \FOR{$p=1:r$} // number of rows
        \STATE $x=1$
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
```

It doesn't work. I couldn't find any way to put the `comments` to the same line with `for`. Is there any way to do that with the algorithmic package?

## EDIT

### 1.

Code:

```
\FOR[// loop over all puppies]{$p=1:r$}
    \STATE $x=1$
\ENDFOR
```

Result:

```
for i = 1 : z do {// number of rows}
   x = 1 
end for
```

### 2.

Code:

```
\FOR{$p=1:r$ \COMMENT{// number of rows}}
    \STATE $x=1$
\ENDFOR
```

Result:

```
for i = 1 : z {// number of rows} do
   x = 1 
end for
```

Is there any way to get rid of these curly brackets?

Comment: Would http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/algorithm-package-comment-on-for-loop-does-not-work help you?

Comment: @Caramdir: I use `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages.

Comment: @Caramdir: I edited the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the package defines

```
  \newcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\{#1\}}
```

so if you go

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{#1}
```

the braces will be gone.